# Do I need an iOS device to test PhoneGap Built apps?

Tags: ios, cordova

I'm a complete noob and figuring out all this as I go along so bear with me.

I've built an app using jQuery Mobile, used PhoneGap Build and it works totally fine on Android and I'll deploy it soon. I'm now trying to figure out the more complex steps towards getting it ready for the iOS market. I've got my developer account set up and have tested my app as built with Xcode 4.2 and Cordova.

What I'm having confusion over (well one of the things) is whether or not I need an actual iOS device in order to get the proper provisioning and certificates. Can I get those, run the package through PG Build and then test it with the Xcode iOS simulator? Must I bother my friends to give me one of their iPhones to test on?

If I'm being vague or asking this the wrong way I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm currently building an app for iOS using Phonegap and even though I have done some testing with a physical device I have seen that the simulator works really well. I mean it would definitely be a good idea to at least run one test of your final version on a physical device before you decide to submit, Apple and pretty much everyone else [very strongly suggest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/YourFirstAppStoreSubmission/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions/TestYourApponManyDevicesandiOSVersions.html) that you do, but you aren't required to test on a physical device. All the provisioning and certificate stuff can be done through the [Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/) site.

The only real reason I could see your app not getting approved relating to this topic is if there is some weird glitch that is only present on a physical device and looks fine on the simulator.

And keep in mind, though it probably won't get you disapproved I've noticed that Phonegap apps that use jQuery Mobile tend to be more glitchy on the transitions compared to when they are run on the simulator.

Comment: I just ran it through PGB and it gave me an .ipa so it seems to mostly work. I just want to make sure that there's no freak error that makes it not work. I had that happen while I was testing my android app.

Comment: I've had more problems bringing apps that I built originally for iOS using Phonegap to Android than the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need an iOS device to get certificates. You can get them using OpenSSL. I created a GUI to help do just this for Windows users.

However Apple is one of the strictest in approval. It takes 8 days for them to approve an app. And they have been know to not approve apps simply because of there appearance.

Now I myself prefer to have iDevices to test apps.

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/detailed_guide_for_setting_up_building_ios_apps_without_a_mac

http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/ios_app_rejected_advice_on_how_to_fix_it

To help with some App Rejection issues you may get when submitting the app.
https://github.com/AndiDog/phonegap-ios-tabbar-plugin

https://github.com/LinuxPhreak/iOS-Win-Signer

You will need an Apple computer to submit apps to the App Store. Apple no longer has a web based App Submission